# Azure Logic App won't listen for updates on certain SQL Server Tables

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I'm having issues with a logic app that is listening every 3 seconds for a table update on an Azure SQL database. It seems like the issue is that the logic app only successfully listens to tables that appear in this autocomplete drop down here, there are only 3. The rest must be entered as a "custom value".

[image]

It is unsuccessful for any other table, other than the three in the dropdown, there are about 30 or so more tables that don't appear here. When entering tables as a custom value, the logic app has knowledge of column names, etc. as dynamic content, so it's not a typo or anything like that

As an FYI this is a very large, enterprise level database with millions of records, so I'm not sure if the logic app is having trouble with schema introspection on such a large database, but I'm at a loss at this point what the issue is, or how to get more tables to appear, or if my intuition is incorrect and there is some other issue causing this.

Thanks for any advice and help.

Answer (score 2):

Its an old question, but if this helps somebody.

This SQL trigger to get invoked the table should have an identity column (a column like serial number or something which increases or decreases in a progression). Only those tables with identity keys will be listed in the drop down.